# MySQL: Expanding table with new rows including two table data

Tags: mysql, sql

My table was enough to get what I needed at the beginning of the project but now I need to expand it.

Table `s_ogr`

```
id | ad | numara | yurt_id | egitim_id | yetkili_id | yetkili_ad
```

Current Table `s_kontrol`

```
id | ogr_id | tur_id | durum_id | tarih | egitim_id | yurt_id
```

What is needed `s_kontrol_k`

```
id | ogr_id | ogr_numara |ogr_ad | tur_id | durum_id | tarih | egitim_id | yurt_id
```

**Explanation of rows** `ad = name` , `ogr_id` is `student_id` , `yurt_id` is `department_id`

**My Sittuation**; `s_kontrol` is full of data over 24000. I need it to expand `s_kontrol_k` , but new two fields should be taken from `s_ogr` table , by the match operation of `s_ogr` and `s_kontrol` (s_ogr.id=s_kontrol.ogr_id and s_ogr.yurt_id =s_kontrol.yurt_id). I see that my mistake is not to add the `ogr_id` as `id` of student into `s_kontrol`

**What I need**; a Helpful query that copies the data from source but how to fill new fields from the third table with right values

```
INSERT INTO s_kontrol_k ( id ,  ogr_id ,  tur_id ,  durum_id ,  tarih ,  egitim_id ,  yurt_id )

SELECT  id ,  ogr_id ,  tur_id ,  durum_id ,  tarih ,  egitim_id ,  yurt_id  FROM s_kontrol
```

The queries that I am having a problem that is why I need a simple table

```
SELECT s_kontrol.ogr_id,
s_ogr.ad, 
s_kontrol.tur_id, 
s_kontrol.durum_id,
SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 else 0 end) var,
SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) gorevli,
SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 3 THEN 1 else 0 end) yok,
SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 4 THEN 1 else 0 end) izinli,
SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 5 THEN 1 else 0 end) hatimde 
FROM s_kontrol, s_ogr 
WHERE s_kontrol.ogr_id=s_ogr.numara 
AND s_kontrol.yurt_id=s_ogr.yurt_id 
and s_ogr.yurt_id=? 
and tarih BETWEEN ? and ? 
and tur_id IN (?) 
GROUP BY s_kontrol.ogr_id
```

Second one

```
select deneme.ogr_id,
deneme.ad,
sum(case deneme.tur_id WHEN 1 THEN YUZDE else 0 END) sabah ,
sum(case deneme.tur_id WHEN 2 THEN YUZDE else 0 END) ogle,
sum(case deneme.tur_id WHEN 4 THEN YUZDE else 0 END) aksam,
sum(case deneme.tur_id WHEN 5 THEN YUZDE else 0 END) yatsi,
sum(case deneme.tur_id WHEN 6 THEN YUZDE else 0 END) sohbet,
sum(case deneme.tur_id WHEN 7 THEN YUZDE else 0 END) muhtelif 
FROM (
      SELECT s_kontrol.ogr_id, 
      s_ogr.ad,tur_id, 
      CEILING(((SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 else 0 end)
      +SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 2 THEN 1 else 0 end)
      +SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 3 THEN 1 else 0 end)
      +SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 4 THEN 1 else 0 end)
      +SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 5 THEN 1 else 0 end) )
      -(SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 3 THEN 1 else 0 end)))
      /(SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 else 0 end)
      +SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 2 THEN 1 else 0 end)
      +SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 3 THEN 1 else 0 end)
      +SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 4 THEN 1 else 0 end)
      +SUM(case s_kontrol.durum_id WHEN 5 THEN 1 else 0 end) ) 
      * 100) YUZDE 
      FROM s_kontrol, s_ogr 
      WHERE s_kontrol.ogr_id=s_ogr.numara 
      and s_ogr.yurt_id=? 
      and tarih BETWEEN ? and ? 
      and tur_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
      GROUP BY s_kontrol.ogr_id,s_ogr.ad, tur_id 
     ) deneme 
group by ogr_id,ad order by 1
```

Comment: In select query you can use Join of s_ogr table

Comment: please provide example data sources and an expected end result.

Comment: @fyrye not able to do it right now, maybe I was editing other parts that is why. It says Aprroved at the moment. Sorry if something gone wrong

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra tried many join thing, missing some logic.

Comment: @Sam could you please list all column which you want to insert into **s_kontrol_k** from **kontrol_k** and **s_ogr** ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra all colums that s_kontrol has as you notice I just need to add two more colums from s_ogr , name and id with correct values

Comment: Are you sure you want to combine two tables? In terms of normalization, this does not look good....

Comment: You are right. but its not that big data organization, maximum recorded data will be over 250 000.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below.

```
INSERT INTO s_kontrol_k 
( id ,  ogr_id , ogr_ad , tur_id ,  durum_id ,  tarih ,  egitim_id ,  yurt_id )

SELECT  o.id ,  o.ogr_id ,  o.ogr_ad , 
s.tur_id ,  s.durum_id ,  s.tarih ,  s.egitim_id ,  s.yurt_id  
FROM 
s_kontrol s inner join s_ogr o on o.yurt_id =s.yurt_id;


INSERT INTO s_kontrol_k (
id, ogr_id, ogr_numara, ogr_ad, tur_id, 
durum_id, tarih, egitim_id, yurt_id) 
SELECT 
s_kontrol.id, 
s_ogr.id, 
s_kontrol.ogr_id, 
s_ogr.ad, 
s_kontrol.tur_id, 
s_kontrol.durum_id, 
s_kontrol.tarih, 
s_kontrol.egitim_id, 
s_kontrol.yurt_id FROM 
s_kontrol inner join  
s_ogr WHERE 
s_ogr.yurt_id = s_kontrol.yurt_id 
and s_ogr.numara = s_kontrol.ogr_id
```

Comment: problem is o.id and s.ogr_id are not same thing  , only o.yurt_id and s.yurt_id are same

Comment: Ok then use that two in join condition

Comment: maybe I need an other approach

Comment: why r u doing cross join ?

Comment: I didn't type cross join, after where key inner join or my type of join is same as I know.

Answer (score 0):

First copied the same columns

```
INSERT INTO s_kontrol_k (
id, ogr_numara, tur_id, durum_id, tarih, 
egitim_id, yurt_id)
SELECT 
id, 
ogr_id, 
tur_id, 
durum_id, 
tarih, 
egitim_id, 
yurt_id 
FROM 
s_kontrol
```

Then Updated values

```
UPDATE 
s_kontrol_k 
INNER JOIN s_ogr ON s_kontrol_k.ogr_numara = s_ogr.numara 
and s_kontrol_k.yurt_id = s_ogr.yurt_id SET s_kontrol_k.ogr_id = s_ogr.id

UPDATE 
s_kontrol_k 
INNER JOIN s_ogr ON s_kontrol_k.ogr_numara = s_ogr.numara 
and s_kontrol_k.yurt_id = s_ogr.yurt_id SET 
s_kontrol_k.ogr_ad = s_ogr.ad
```

Could be updated on main table by adding new rows